# My textbox RequiredFieldValidator fires but doesn't stop post when javascript added to checkbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a requiredfieldvalidator that works when it is all by itself (fires and stops post back), but when I add the javascript to enable the "next" button when the checkbox is checked, the requiredfieldvalidator will fire when clicking "next" when txtEmail is blank, but it will not stop the post from executing.  How do I get this to work?

```
    <ul>
    <li>FirstName<asp:textbox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:textbox></li>
     <li>LastName<asp:textbox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:textbox></li>
     <li>Email<asp:textbox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group"></asp:textbox></li>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="group" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


    </ul>
    </div> 
    <div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="ckAgree" onclick="EnableSubmit(this)"/>
    I agree to the <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">terms and  conditions</a>

    <asp:button ID="btnNext" runat="server" text="Next" Enabled="false" ValidationGroup="group" OnClick="btnNext_Click" />

    <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><asp:HiddenField ID="hf_ID" runat="server" />


    ***javascript**:
    EnableSubmit = function (val) {

    var sbmt = document.getElementById("btnNext");

    if (val.checked == true) {
       sbmt.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
       sbmt.disabled = true;
    }
```

}

Comment: put `CausesValidation="true"` in your submit button

Comment: tried that, still raised a postback-thx

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any kind of validator for the check box, so yes, the button is still going to cause a postback if it's clicked and the button is enabled.

On the server side, just include a check to Page.IsValid in the event code for btnNext.  If IsValid is false, don't do anything.

Comment: I tried using the customFieldValidator and I had equal frustration the requiredFieldValidator would work but not the other, it would cause a postback so I moved to just disabling the button on a click. Without the javascript, the required field validator works perfectly, no post.

Answer (score 0):

So all you have to do is add AutoPostBack="false"

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="group" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

reason it was doing that is because it was doing a postback and starting the session over.

Then why not do this

```
EnableSubmit = function (val) {

        var sbmt = document.getElementById("btnNext");

        if (val.checked == true && $('[id="txtEmail"]').val() != "") {
            sbmt.disabled = false;

        }
        else {
            sbmt.disabled = true;

        }
    }
```

Here you are checking if anything is even in the textbox. If nothing is in textbox, it will not enable the Button. Just a suggestion.